# With the last.fm API, is there a way to get the top tracks for a time period with a supplied start and end date?

Tags: last.fm

Is there anyway to use user.getTopTracks for a time period, with a start and end, as opposed to a time duration?

I know you can send a period parameter such as 7day, 3month etc, which returns the top track for that period up until the present day, but is there anyway to get the top tracks like this: for the time period 1 Jan 07 - 31 Feb 07?

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From here http://www.last.fm/api/show?service=301 it's the only way you can access the API, but unfortunately I think there's no other way. You'll have to use fixed periods. That's a limitation.

Comment: Thanks for your help. After a little more research, I think user.getWeeklyTrackChart will suffice for what I need. Thanks again.